# How to configure internet on CentOS installation on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I am a beginner to linux. I have done the fresh installation of CentOS 7 on my Windows VirtualBox.

Over the tutorials for CentOs 6 they have mentioned to edit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file for the configurations.

But in my installation there is no such file. I have ifcfg-enp0s3 and ifcfg-lo files available.

Comment: Is this a headless install?

Answer (score 3):

From the CentOS tutorial, the `eth0` portion of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` refers to the network interface.  `eth0` is the most common name for a standard ethernet interface in Linux.  From your question, your system has two interfaces: `enp0s3` and `lo`.  `lo` is the loopback interface, so ignore that one.  That leaves `enp0s3`.

Go ahead and follow the instructions with `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`.  It should work, assuming that interface doesn't have any weird quirks associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

Same here! I installed CentOS 7 in Windows7 Virtulabox, there is no `eth0`, but `enp0s3`.

- After first reboot, used command `ip addr`, `enp0s3` had no ip address
  bundled;
- Then I updated `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`, changed `ONBOOT=no` to `ONBOOT=yes`, `enp0s3` had ip 10.x.x.x, still useless;

Then I updated `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` according to the accepted answer of [centos minimal installation static ip address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278637/centos-minimal-installation-static-ip-address), it works!
As my IP address of `Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network` is 192.168.56.1, I set 192.168.56.35 to `enp0s3`, and my vbox NIC mode is `Host-Only`.

Answer (score 2):

- Type nmtui in the terminal
- Go to 'edit connection' and hit enter
- Select 'enp0s3' and hit enter
- Go down to 'Automatically connect' using down arrow key
- Press space bar
- Go down and press hit enter on 'Ok'
- Go back and quit

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me like this on windows 10 -Change Adapter 1 Name to "Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device"